# Cant start mysql, no change has been made

Tags: mysql, apache, configuration, server

Mysql doest not want to start, I have solve some warning messages, but im not able to solve the warnings below. No changes were made to the server, it just stopped working.

```
170529 10:05:39 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/panel.lower-test
170529 10:05:39 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Location is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
170529 10:05:39 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) starting as process 2410 ...
170529 10:05:39 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 150  table_cache: 432
170529 10:05:39 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/panel.lower-test
170529 10:05:39 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/panel.lower-test
```

Comment: Do try to start mysql as root? Looks like you do not have the permission to wirte in the Directory that is mentioned

Comment: @Jens, yes im the root on the server, i have full access. Ive changed secure-file-priv = /var/temp to secure-file-priv = /var/lib/mysql-files/
now the Insecure configuration was remove, but I still got to solve the cant create test file...

Comment: I guess you checked for free space in the file system?

Comment: @jan theres plenty of free space.